# Can I develop ios apps with xamarin on windows?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I don't have any mac and I want to develop a mobile app on a cross-platform.
Do I have a chance to develop an app for Android at the same time for IOS without mac os?

Comment: When you make a new project on visual studio it does say OS apps in C# however I have never tried it sorry

Answer (score 0):

There is website called MacInCloud that can be used. Xamarin actually recommends it for their Dev Days events for developers that don't have a mac. From their [website](https://ti.to/xamarin/dev-days-kansas-city):

> In order to test the part of iOS , for those who do not have a MAC , you can use one of the weekly plans MacInCloud https://www.macincloud.com/checkout/managed.html ( Europe Server , OS El Capitain ) with the option Enable Remote Build Port enabled.

It might work for what you need.